# "angular" not found, trying to get values & validate from HTML form

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, components

I am new to Angular and I want to use `angular.module('FooApp', []);` to retrive HTML form data and validate it from my `.ts component file`.

It seems that `"angular"` is not even recognized in my IDE (Visual Studio Code). I do not know the library that I need to use for this.

I am trying to do this (Scroll down to Custom Validation): https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="infoForm" (ngSubmit)="validateForm()" my-directive>

  <label>First Name </label> <input type="text" maxlength="25" name="first" 
autofocus required /><br><br>
  <label>Last Name </label> <input type="text" maxlength="25" name="last" 
required /><br><br>
....
</form>

<script src="data-form.component.ts"></script>
```

.ts File:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-form',
  templateUrl: './data-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-form.component.css']
})

export class DataFormComponent implements OnInit {

  infoForm: FormGroup;

  // The form values for a user
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
     this.infoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     firstName: ['', Validators.required],
     lastName: ['', Validators.required],
     ....
  })
 }

  clearForm() {
    // Get the Form names and make them null to clear the form
  }

  // Incomplete Implementation, where the error is
  validateForm() {

    // The error is here
    var app = angular.module('FooApp', []);

    if (this.infoForm.invalid) {
      return;

    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

The Error:

[image]

Cannot find name, "angular".

My project structure:

[image]

To get an overall idea of what environment I am working in https://youtu.be/5wtnKulcquA?t=372

Comment: You seem to be mixing up AngularJS and Angular.

Comment: Oh, is it just Angular?

Comment: Sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: You're using Angular (2+). The site you link to is using AngularJS (1.x). They aren't compatible.

Comment: Hmm, thank you for the feedback. Then is there another resource that I could use to achieve the same task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments says you are mixing AngularJS and Angular.

In your code:

```
if (this infoForm.invalid)
```

You are verifying if your form is invalid.
If you want to do this for every control, you can access them from 'infoForm':

```
this.infoForm.controls.firstName.invalid
```

Here a picture of the informations in ***this.infoForm.controls.firstName***
[Debug information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YU0Y1.png)

A control is a **FormControl** type. You can detect if it's invalid / touched / dirty / pristine ...

[Form Control official documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl)

Comment: I am using Angular not AngularJS.

Comment: I am not sure if the infoForm data is even assigned the form's values from the HTML. I can assess each control like you wrote, but I am unsure if there is even data in there.

Comment: It's why I wanted to use the module() method to get the values and validate them.

Comment: I add some informations and the link to the official documentation about FormControl. If I need to add explanations tell me.

Comment: Is your infoForm variable of type FormGroup shown in the debug picture?